# How to toggle between elements in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two elements, only one of them is supposed to show up at a time while the other element stays hidden until the visible element is made to disappear (button click), here an example of the last logic I have tried to use.

```
.......
<div ng-show='show'>
Visible element
<button ng-click='toggle()'> Toggle </button>
</div>
<div ng-hide='show'>
Hidden Element
</div>
```

.......

And I have something like this in my controller

```
........
$scope.show = true;
$scope.toggle = function(){
$scope.show =!$scope.show;
}
.........
```

Now, anytime I click the button, the first element will disappear but the second element will not show. Please I really need help.

Comment: this is working fine as written:  http://plnkr.co/edit/vJVKBkYiI3foDnsaYG7F?p=info.  If it's not working in your code, you **probably** have the two elements in different scopes. You should read up on how the `$scope` object works in AngularJs, and consider **always use a dot in HTML bindings**.  Also, you might want to move the button outside of the elements that are being toggled, i.e. http://plnkr.co/edit/a5IBc3THG9hYws5QEVLp

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Heirarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies). We can't tell from the code snippets in the queston, but it is likely a scoping issue.

Comment: Yeah I can see it works fine here, but why isn't it working on my code, what could I be doing wrong? Anyway let me check the angular developer guide

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your button out of the ng-show div like this

```
<div ng-show='show'>
    <div>Visible element</div>

</div>

<div ng-hide='show'>
    <div>Hidden Element</div>
</div>
<button ng-click='toggle()'> Toggle </button>
```

then its work fine. Hope this help...

Comment: It is still not working, the hidden element doesn't appear

Comment: Its work in my system. You can please check once again in your system

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.show = true;
$scope.toggle = function(){
$scope.show =!$scope.show;
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-show='show'>
    Visible element
  </div>

  <div ng-hide='show'>
    Hidden Element
  </div>
  <button ng-click='toggle()'> Toggle </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I m able to see ^^ , which browser you're using share screenshot