# Toggle between elements on button click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two divs and want to toggle between them by clicking on button. The following is the code I have tried:

```
<div id="one" *ngIf="show == true">
     Hello One
</div>
<div id="two" *ngIf="show == false">
     Hello Two
</div>
<button ng-init="show=true">Click to toggle</button>
```

I want to toggle between two divs on button click, somehow it is not happening in this case. I am suspecting that show is never set to false. What could be my mistake. I am a rookie in AngularJS. How can I achieve toggle btween two elements on button click? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `ng-init="show=true"`, try `ng-click="toggle()"` and extend the controller with the toggle function, as shown in your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of `*ngIf`, you have to write `ng-if`. The former notation is for Angular and the latter is for AngularJS (the predecessor of Angular, which you are using).

Secondly, you are right that `show` is never set to false in your code. You need to write a function in the controller that can toggle the value of `show`, as follows:

```
constructor($scope) {

    $scope.show = true;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.show =!$scope.show;
    }
}
```

Then, the html can be as follows:

```
<div id="one" ng-if="show">
     Hello One
</div>
<div id="two" ng-if="!show">
     Hello Two
</div>
<button ng-click="toggle()">Click to toggle</button>
```

Comment: Yep, got my mistake! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it using ng-show and ng-hide. Used the following:

```
<div id="one" ng-show="show>
    Hello One
</div>
<div id="two" ng-hide="show">
    Hello Two
</div>
<button ng-click="toggle()">Click to toggle</button>
```

In the Controller, added this:

```
$scope.show = true;
$scope.toggle = function(){
    $scope.show =!$scope.show;
}
```

Ref: [How to toggle between elements in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655476/how-to-toggle-between-elements-in-angularjs)

I have achieved my goal, but would surely want to know how do we do it via ng-If

Comment: What happens if you take this solution and replace the divs with the divs containing the ng-ifs as shown in your question?

Comment: There is another problem: you wrote *ngIf instead of ng-if. I have added an answer with a working example. If you are satisfied with that answer, please mark it with a checkmark.